# Default route and backup default route

Tags: networking, routing

I am dealing with the following topology:

[image]

I have an "ISP ROUTER" connected via fastethernet to a MAIN router. "ISP ROUTER" is also connected via serial link to router CITY. CITY and MAIN are connected to each other via serial link.

The default route to the "ISP ROUTER" has to go through the fastEthernet connection on MAIN(out of fa0/1). However if the connection  between "ISP ROUTER" and MAIN fails I should use the backup route from CITY router to "ISP ROUTER". I have to use static routes, no dynamic protocols are allowed on the connection to "ISP ROUTER". However between CITY and MAIN (and the rest) OSPF is configured.

So far I configured two default static routes for each router, the backup one has an administrative distance greater than the default one.

My problem is that when the connection fails I generate a loop, because MAIN redirects the traffic to city, but then CITY will still send it back to MAIN, because CITY does not know the connection is down.

How do I get CITY to know that the connection between "ISP ROUTER" and MAIN failed?

Comment: ISP is serial connected to CITY but the route to the ISP is out of MAIN via ethernet?  Huh?  You got a drawing to help explain?

Comment: I can't upload picture yet...

Comment: I think I "see" it now...I'm going to edit your question and if I am incorrect please remove my edits.  Trying to add clarity where you keep saying ISP and mean "ISP router".

Comment: @TheCleaner Yeah now it looks better, thank you. Do you "see" the topology now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved my problem. Because both on CITY and MAIN OSPF is configured, i set up a default route to ISP on main and then issue the command `default-information originate`. This will propagate my default route. Also MAIN router will update any change that happens to the default route.
Then on CITY i configure a default route to ISP but with a administrative distance greater than 110(OSPF).
It seems now that everything is working

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an `ip sla` that will ping out of the relevant interface to whatever will fail to respond under a failure condition. Then you should create a `track` object to reference the `ip sla` and finally, your static route should reference it.

[example here](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3560/software/release/12.2_52_se/configuration/guide/sweot.html#wp1086250)

Comment: Thanx for your help! I think it is a bit more complicate than my course...I am doing CCNA2 now and so far I haven't seen this things. I'll have a look into it, see if I get it working.

Answer (score 0):

If you have both CITY and MAIN connected to the ISP ROUTER, why the need for the extra default hop from CITY to MAIN during normal operation?

Why not let both have a default route to the ISP ROUTER with a backup default route to each other?

Comment: You I like your idea much better and it makes more sense, but the specs state that besides the primary Ethernet connection between Main and ISP router, XXX has purchased a backup serial link which automatically becomes available only when the primary ISP via Main fails. So I have to stick with this.

Comment: Is the requirement a hypothetical CCNA course simulation or real life?